# How to add border width and color for heatmap in High Charts for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, highcharts, heatmap

I am trying to use heatmap with high charts library in the iOS application. I am able to display the heatmap and data but I want to display border between the series data. I am not able to see the borderWidth or borderColor property in it.

However when I check their documentation for map using html and css, both the properties  are present and working in it.

This is my heatmap source code for instantiate the heatmap and adding dummy data in it.

```
    var heatmap = HIHeatmap()
    heatmap.dataLabels = HIDataLabels()
    heatmap.dataLabels.enabled = NSNumber(booleanLiteral: true)
    heatmap.dataLabels.color = HIColor(hexValue: "000000")
    heatmap.enableMouseTracking = NSNumber(booleanLiteral: false)
    heatmap.data = [[0, 0, 10], [0, 1, 19], [0, 2, 8], [0, 3, 24], [0, 4, 67], [0, 5, 20],[0,6,34],[0,7,34234]]
```